# Trying to extract items from a nested javascript object tree using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I'm trying to learn recursion and I have a code that tries to extract all parent names and push them to array if they have children.

My problem is that I am able to print out all the parents but can only seem to push 2 out of 5 of them.

```js
function printChildrenRecursive(t) {
  let hasChildren = []

  if (t.children.length === 0) {
    return
  }

  t.children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.children.length > 0) {
      console.log(child.name)
      hasChildren.push(child.name)
    }
    printChildrenRecursive(child)
  })

  return hasChildren
}

const tree = {
  name: 'John',
  children: [{
      name: 'Jim',
      children: [{
        name: 'Joe',
        children: [{
          name: 'Lee',
          children: []
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Zoe',
      children: [{
          name: 'Kyle',
          children: [{
            name: 'Tony',
            children: []
          }]
        },
        {
          name: 'Sophia',
          children: [{
            name: 'Thor',
            children: []
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let res = printChildrenRecursive(tree)
console.log(res);
```

The console.log outputs

```
Jim
Joe
Zoe
Kyle
Sophia
```

But the hasChildren.push only outputs

```
(2) ["Jim", "Zoe"]
```

Comment: Is `printChildrenRecursive` is a strange name for a function that should return an array of parents.

Comment: I know, I was just following a tutorial about printing children but forgot about it as I tried to tinker with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places where you do not deal well with the array that should be returned:

1. In the base case, don't just `return`, but do `return []`
2. In the recursive case, don't ignore the value that is returned from the recursive call, but append it to your current array.

Here is the correction:

```js
function printChildrenRecursive(t) {
  let hasChildren = [];
  if (t.children.length === 0) {
    return []; // always return an array!
  }
  t.children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.children.length > 0) {
      console.log(child.name);
      hasChildren.push(child.name);
    }
    // add the returned array: 
    hasChildren.push(...printChildrenRecursive(child));
  })
  return hasChildren;
}

const tree = {name: 'John',children: [{name: 'Jim',children: [{name: 'Joe',children: [{name: 'Lee',children: []}]}]},{name: 'Zoe',children: [{name: 'Kyle',children: [{name: 'Tony',children: []}]},{name: 'Sophia',children: [{name: 'Thor',children: []}]}]}]};

let result = printChildrenRecursive(tree);
console.log(result);
```

### Alternative solution

The algorithm does not return the root node, as it focuses on *children* -- possibly this is intended.

Also the order of output is a mix of breadth-first and depth-first. The more common order for recursion would be a depth-first order -- like preorder.

And why not use a generator.

Here is an implementation of that:

```js
function *dfs(node) {
    // If you want to include leaves, remove the condition:
    if (node.children.length) yield node.name; 
    for (let child of node.children) yield *dfs(child);
}

const tree = {name: 'John',children: [{name: 'Jim',children: [{name: 'Joe',children: [{name: 'Lee',children: []}]}]},{name: 'Zoe',children: [{name: 'Kyle',children: [{name: 'Tony',children: []}]},{name: 'Sophia',children: [{name: 'Thor',children: []}]}]}]};

let result = Array.from(dfs(tree));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What about John? It should be added too, no?

Comment: @Sergey, apparently it was not the intention of the Asker to get the root. Their function name hints to this.

Answer (score 1):

Trincot already showed what was wrong with your implementation.

I would like to note that this can be written more simply.  Here's a simple recursive function to collect the names of all the parent nodes:

```js
const parents = ({name, children}) => 
  children .length > 0
    ? [name, ... children .flatMap (parents)]
    : []


const tree = {name: 'John', children: [{name: 'Jim', children: [{name: 'Joe', children: [{name: 'Lee', children: []}]}]}, {name: 'Zoe', children: [{name: 'Kyle', children: [{name: 'Tony', children: []}]}, {name: 'Sophia', children: [{name: 'Thor', children: []}]}]}]}

console .log (parents (tree))
```

If it's possible that some nodes will not have the `children` property, it's only slightly more complex:

```js
const parents = ({name, children}) => 
  (children || []) .length > 0
    ? [name, ... children .flatMap (parents)]
    : []
```

If your requirement is to print them, then you can call this and print the results.  I would suggest that you make it a habit to separate I/O from the core of your logic.